# Android Studio Drawable Folder

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

this is the code containing my error in Android Studio.

the error says

Rendering Problems NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.

```
 Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/chrysanthemum
```

Here's the code that I typed in the **activity_main.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:src="@drawable/chrysanthemum"
    </ImageView>

       </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to resolve this resource problem. This is actually my very first time to use Android Studio. I'm really new to this software.

Comment: Why didn't you close the ImageView tag properly?

Comment: I edited it and still the same, but it rendered a new note error

Failed to convert drawable/tulipsflower into a drawable

Comment: please post this xml

Comment: Moreover, the explicit closing tag isn't needed at all. You can close the View tag like this: `/>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,Just ***Rebuild and Clean your Project*** .Then

**File → Invalidate caches / Restart→ Just Restart**.
Oh one thing .Its your biggest mistake .Please close your Imageview tag  Like this way,

```
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:src="@drawable/chrysanthemum"
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed ">" character:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:src="@drawable/chrysanthemum">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Moreover, the explicit closing tag isn't needed at all. You can close the View tag like this: `/>`

Answer (score 0):

Fix your xml code. Add a closing tag to your ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/chrysanthemum" />
```